# set checkbox using watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, watir

```
<div class="icheckbox_minimal" style="position: relative;">
 <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="order[terms]" 
  id="order_terms" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; 
  display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;     
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;">
 <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; 
  display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; 
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;">
 </ins>
</div>
```

How can I set the checkbox for this element?

I tried the following

`browser.checkbox(:class => "iCheck-helper").when_present.set`

`browser.div(:class => "icheckbox_minimal").fire_event :click`

Answer (score 1):

you can click on ins tag to set the check box value as given below.

```
if !browser.checkbox(id: 'order_terms').set? then
   puts "not set"
   browser.element(class: 'iCheck-helper').click
end
puts browser.checkbox(id: 'order_terms').set?
```

Comment: You don't have to do this checking, WATIR is creating object for checkbox and related methods are immediately avialable to you. So you don't have to check whether it is set or not If you `b.checkbox().set` It will set if it is not set, if it is set, then it would leave untouched. If you use b.element().click, then you have to take care of the above conditions as you have written. Selenium creates the common objects for elements, but WATIR creates the more abstracted version by creating the object for each type like Text_field has it's own object, so it's methods are separated.

Comment: Omar has overlapping issue.  He couldn't interact directly with check box.  Also, I am clicking on ins tag which is top of the checkbox.  if i click on ins element, it will set/unset indirectly. So that, I have used it here. please wait till omar comes back.

Comment: Watir has a class and method for `ins` elements. Might be more clear to do `browser.ins(class: 'iCheck-helper').click`

Comment: `if !browser.checkbox(id: 'order_terms').set? then
   puts "not set"
   browser.element(class: 'icheckbox_minimal',:index => 1).click
end` I think you helped but this was the solution

Comment: I'd be careful with this being unique. Consider a variant of: `browser.checkbox(id: 'order_terms').next_sibling(tag_name: 'ins').click`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 browser.checkbox(id: "order_terms").set
```

When you locate an element, that element has to be checkbox when you use the method checkbox but you are passing the locator of div to checkbox method.

Comment: i get an error in the console, something like =unknown error :Element <input class="checkbox" ..../> is not clickable at point (541,520). Other element would recieve the click <ins class="iCheck-helper" ... />

Comment: @omar Try to use explicit wait before clicking on element.

Comment: @GautamBothra Explicit wait is not necessary if you use WATIR, If you use Ruby Selenium Binding directly, then you may need to use it. WATIR waits for element to exist,visible,enabled and then it would performs the click. But the above error happened due to overlay of another element, when this error happens, predefined Exception is available only to Firefox, it's not available for Chrome nor for Edge. And also WATIR is not rescuing this for many reasons. Some of the overlay is permanent so they are not rescuing this error. Perhaps in future they may do, but not available right now.

Comment: @Omar Okay, so it identified the element correctly the problem is another element is overlay this element. And also I saw you were triggering the Javascript click to the parent of the checkbox but it's not working. So do one thing.  Put this code in begin end block and rescue with retry and check whether it works. Because in my application, element would soon be available to me from this state.